как вызвать функцию один раз, чтобы за ней пошла другая функция
Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы функция сработала раз и потом после нее шла уже другая функция
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
root=Tk()
root.config(bg="lightpink")
lab1=Label(root, text="Правильные слова: 0",bg="lightpink")
lab2=Label(root, text="Ошибки: 0",bg="lightpink")
ent=Entry(root,width=20,bd=3)
lab1.pack(anchor=NW)
lab2.pack(anchor=W)
ent.pack(anchor=CENTER)

r=0
m=0
t=0


def w():
        canv=Canvas(root, width=600, height=300, bg="lightblue1")
        canv.pack()
        canv.create_text(300,150,text="Д_ирижировать",font="Verdana 12")
        def f(event):
            global r
            global m
            global a
            a=ent.get()
            if a=="и":
                
                r+=1
                lab1.config(text="Правильные слова:" + str(r))
                False
        
            else:
                m+=1
                lab2.config(text="Ошибки:" + str(m))
                    
        root.bind("<Return>",f)      

       

def l():
    canv=Canvas(root, width=600, height=300, bg="lightblue1")
    canv.pack()
    canv.create_text(300,150,text="под_линник",font="Verdana 12")
    def g(event):
        global r
        global m
        a=ent.get()
        if a=="у":
        
            r+=1
            lab1.config(text="Правильные слова:" + str(r))
        else:
            m+=1
            lab2.config(text="Ошибки:" + str(m))
            
    root.bind("<Return>",g)


    


    
    
   


Не понятно, как у вас функции должны "срабатывать", опишите подробнее

в начале должна сработать функция w() один раз по нажатию , далее l() дин раз так же по нажатию в функции  то бишь ентер

Ну делайте bind второй функции при вызове первой

можете пожалуйста поподробней объяснить как это сделать, немного не понимаю как

Ну условно, чтобы w вызывалось при нажатии на enter, у вас где-то должен быть код root.bind("<Return>", w). В самой функции w делаете root.bind("<Return>", l).

Вызвать две функции можно так:
def func1 ():
// code of func1
    // ...
    return 1
def func2:
    // ...
    return 2
// call of func1
func1();
//call of func2
func2();

В вашем случае:
w()
l()

Если Нужно с задержкой то:
import time
def w:
    // code of w ...
def l:
     // code of l ...
w()
time.sleep(1) // sleep 1 second
l()


в таком случае они срабатывают одновременно, а нужно чтобы одна функция сработала один раз, закрылась, и начала срабатывать новая функция в одиночку без другой функции

@ЭвелинаШмидт Дополнил ответ.
